# Cannot make C# constructor compile

Tags: c#, constructor, compilation

Whenever i try to apply my own constructor instead of the default one in VS 2010 I get the compiler error: 
Error   1   The namespace 'global namespace' already contains a definition for 'whatever'

Just as an example the compiler will not let me do this:

```
    public class whatever
    {
        public whatever()
            {
            }
    };
```

Comment: That compiles for me. Can you post the *entire* file (or at least more information about your situation)?

Comment: Is the codebehind of ASPX page?

Comment: There must be more going on than you've shown...like another class whatever declared somewhere else.

Comment: try CTRL + SHIFT + F and search for whatever ...

Comment: No it is not the actual piece of code, however the posted piece of code does not compile for me either. It happens whenever I try to do it. I am currently reading Rob Miles Csharp Yellow book and I am using the code examples from there. I'm sorry for not knowing how to format code in comments. This is currently the entire program, I've trimmed it down as much as possible to find the error, but it still won't compile
Program code found in next comment below.

Comment: using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.IO; enum AccountState { New, Active, UnderAudit, Frozen, Closed }; public class Account { public Account() { } }; class beep { static void Main() { Console.ReadLine(); } }

Comment: @TheExplosiveSheep Do you have multiple files like this (or similar to this) in a single solution? If so, then the compiler is telling you that you have declared `Account` as a class multiple times. You should either be updating the old class, or calling the new classes something different.

Comment: @dlev I must have had yes. I tried deleting everything and retyping it and it suddenly works. I must have made a mistake somewhere and I should have tried doing this before asking for help. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @TheExplosiveSheep Glad we could help. Good luck with your learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comments helped the OP solve the problem. Solution is here.]

The class is declared again in the same namespace in another file in your solution. Make sure that any such classes are renamed or removed, and everything should compile just fine.

Answer (score -1):

In C# the class declaration and the definition are not separated (unlike C++) so you don't need a semi-colon after your class declaration.

*edit*

That error has nothing to do with the sem-colon, it was just something that jumped out at me.  I would have to assume that your class was defined somewhere else in the same namespace.  Is "whatever" really the name of the class you are trying to create?

Comment: That's true, but it should be a comment.

Comment: true, should have made this a comment.

Comment: as 2GDev suggested earlier, try and do a CTRL + SHIFT + F and search your solution for the same class existing in another spot in the solution.  Perhaps from a previous example in the book?